# Bug with AddThis Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, addthis

I got two pages:

1-http://www.aotopo.com.br/servicos/

2-http://www.aotopo.com.br/blog/

In both pages I inserted The addThis plugin.
Local testing is perfect for both, but online just the first one is working.

In 2nd the addThis plugin is located at post-content (just before the "Leia Mais" buttons).

```
(function help(){
    if(somebodyKnowWhy){
        pleaseHelpMe();
        console.log("Thank you!");
    }
})()
```

Comment: Just checked both links and the share buttons look fine and are working.  If it's still not working for you, what browser are you using and have you checked the JavaScript console to see if there are any errors being thrown?

Answer (score 1):

If somebody stumbled up in the same issue, I found the answer by a Wordpress.org member (srijith.v) when I  asked the same question:

@Erick: I couldn't find addthis_widget.js being imported to the page. How did you add AddThis? Did you use the plugin available for WordPress?

You will need to include http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js to the page to render the buttons.

I just added this js to my footer as a source of a script tag and voila.